# How to use 'like' in a Monaca Backend query

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

How do I make a query that uses `like` in Monaca Backend?

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_id like "%bc%"
```

[Criteria - Monaca Docs](https://docs.monaca.io/en/reference/monaca_api/cloud/criteria/)

Not working:

```
db.findMine("name == /bc/","",{limit: 10});
```